# Как подключить jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Начал писать расширение под Chrome, как подключить JQuery, чтобы использовать его. Как подключать его в html я знаю, но как подключить его именно в расширении если нет html?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно прописать внешний файл в манифесте. 
Примерно так:

*manifest.json*

```
{
...
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "js":["jquery.js", ...]
        }
    ]
}
```

Подробнее читайте [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143421/) или [документацию](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) (по-английски)

Comment: Только использовать его для поиска по странице при этом не получится - только для самого расширения.

Comment: @Qwertiy Поясните, пожалуйста

Comment: Сорри, я неправ. Тогда другая проблема - эта штука может навредить странице.

Comment: @Qwertiy Волков бояться... :) Придется постараться максимально изолироваться